# How to get alert for shutdown of python process/abrupt termination?

Tags: python

How we can hook up a code inside a python process so that it should send an alert in case of shutdown of process/abrupt termination ?

Comment: Are you asking about Unix Signal handling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Supervisor Daemon](http://supervisord.org/)

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what exactly you mean.  Shutdown/abort of the process itself?  Or of a child process?

- Shutdown/abort of a process itself:  Have a look at [Pythons atexit module](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html); here you can register a callback for when your program cleanly exits.  But there is absolutely no way for you to catch all circumstances, if your program fails b/o a serious issue (e.g. segfault) your atexit handlers will never get called.  You need a supervising process to catch absolutely all aborts.
- Shutdown/abort of a child process:  If you e.g. use the subprocess module you can simply call poll() or wait() on popen objects to see if the spawned process is dead / wait for them to die.  For a more advanced implementation use Pythons signal module to set a handler for SIGCHLD - this signal is sent to your process whenever one of the child processes terminates.